# How best to customize Visual Studio's code completion and formatting, and keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Using **VS2012**.
What I'd like to do is set the formatting and code completion for different languages, and do some custom key mapping with custom functionality.  The `ReSharper` plugin is great and gives me most of what I need, but I can't run it on my corporate machine.  I thought I might try customizing VS but the ability to control these features was was either not available in `Tools => Options`, or severely limited.   My question is, how is this best handled?  Are there any open source plugins for this, or if not, how best to make these customizations.

Answer (score 0):

as you said, the best plugin is `ReSharper`.
otherwise, within the `Tools - > Customize` you can preety much set everything in any way you like...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. What exact customisations are you looking to do? You can't really replace all of R# functions in one go. But you can get some of the functions by extensions like [VS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd), [VS Commands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/) and [many other available free extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=tools&f%5B1%5D.Type=Tag&f%5B1%5D.Value=Power%20Tools).

If you come up with a list of functions you need, maybe other people can suggest an extension. But ReSharper pays pretty much for itself within couple of weeks of developers time. And if management does not realise that, they are stealing from themselves. Now the problem is to get this across to them. Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396655/resharper-convince-management) can help you with getting R#.